# Flipping Geographic Coordinates in R

Tags: r, coordinates

I'm using R for the first time for a study on grasslands and I need to clip my findings onto a specific map. The trouble I'm having is the coordinates in the data don't match the coordinates on the map, they're mirror images. It's probably extremely simple since I can't find any tutorials or code online for it. Or I'm bad at wording this in search bars, either way, does anyone know how to do this transformation?

Comment: could you add some details about the data you are trying to use and may be a screenshot of what's going wrong

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @iant, more detail is needed, but I'm guessing your coordinates are either in two columns dataframe or a list of tuples.  Assuming you have a dataframe `df` with columns `lat` and `lon` as the first two columns, you might switch the order of the columns:

```
df <- data.frame(lat=c(1,3), lon=c(2,4), more_cols = ...)
df
#  lat lon ...
#1   1   2 ...
#2   3   4 ...
df <- df[,c('lon', 'lat', other_col_names)] 
#or df <- df[c('lon', 'lat', other_col_names)
df
#  lon lat ...
#1   2   1 ...
#2   4   3 ...
```

Alternately, if you have a list `coords` of coordinate vectors or tuples, you might switch the order of each coordinate pair with the following code:

```
coords <- list(c(1,2), c(3,4))
for (coord_index in 1:length(coords)){
    coords[[coord_index]] <- coords[[coord_index]][c(2,1)]
}
coords
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you swap columns? All you have to do is define the correct columns when coercing into a sp object. The columns are not retained and are stored in the coordinates slot. FYI, you do not need a for loop for coercing to a matrix or data.frame object. Just use: do.call("rbind", coords)